# How to find specific subfolders by name and rename them?

Tags: python, operating-system, file-rename

I have a folder in `D:/` have the following structure:

```
folder
        \ tic\file0.jpg
        \ tic\file1.jpg
        \ tic\ tik\ file2.png
        .
        .
        .
        \ tik\xxx.png
        \ tik\yyy.jpg
        \ tik\zzz.png
        .
        .
        .
```

I want to find all subfolders whose name is `tik` from `D:/folder` and rename it to `tok`. How can I do it in Python?

Expected result:

```
folder
        \ tic\file0.jpg
        \ tic\file1.jpg
        \ tic\ tok\ file2.png
        .
        .
        .
        \ tok\xxx.png
        \ tok\yyy.jpg
        \ tok\zzz.png
        .
        .
        .
```

So far, I have tried following code but it doesn't work:

```
import os
import os.path

dir = os.getcwd()
old = "tik"
new = "tok"
for parent, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.find(old)!=-1:
            newName = filename.replace(old, new)
            print(filename, "---->", newName)
            os.rename(os.path.join(parent, filename), os.path.join(parent, newName))
```

**Update:**

I create a fake folder struction named `file` as follows:

[image]

I want to rename `tic` to `toc` with code below:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
path = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\file"       # Path to directory that will be searched

old = "tic"
new = "toc"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):      # os.walk will return all files and folders in your directory
    for name in dirs:                                       # we are only concerned with dirs since you only want to change subfolders
        directoryPath = os.path.join(root, name)            # create a path to subfolder
        if old in directoryPath:                            # if the word tik is found in your path then
            parentDirectory = Path(directoryPath).parent    # save the parent directory path
            os.chdir(parentDirectory)                       # set parent to working directory
            os.rename(old, new)
```

but I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-10-2c40676a9ed9>", line 13, in <module>
    os.rename(old, new)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] System can not find file. : 'tic' -> 'toc'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work well and handles all sub-directories inside your main directory. You will want to add some error handling in case the directory already has a folder named what you intend on changing it to, but this should get you going.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
path = r"Enter_path_to_directory_you_want_to_search"       # Path to directory that will be searched

old = "tik"
new = "tok"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):      # os.walk will return all files and folders in your directory
    for name in dirs:                                       # we are only concerned with dirs since you only want to change subfolders
        directoryPath = os.path.join(root, name)            # create a path to subfolder
        if old in directoryPath:                            # if the word tik is found in your path then
            parentDirectory = Path(directoryPath).parent    # save the parent directory path
            os.chdir(parentDirectory)                       # set parent to working directory
            os.rename(old, new)                             # change child folder from tik to tok
```

Comment: Thanks, I try to replace 'tic' to 'tok', but I get a FileNotFoundError, do you know why?

Comment: @ahbon Can you post the code you used that threw the error?

Comment: It seems can only rename the last level subdirectories without errors.